# How to remove numbers from the url and redirect with 301

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have lots of user profile url and want remove user id from the url and redirect 301 with .htaccess
For example my current url is http://www.example.com/1084-jerome-smith/profile.php and want redirect this way http://www.example.com/jerome-smith/profile.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)/[\d]+-(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/%2  [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect permanently:

`http://www.example.com/1084-jerome-smith/profile.php`

To:

`http://www.example.com/jerome-smith/profile.php`

---

Will redirect any URL with this format: `http://www.example.com/OptionalFolders/NumericID-anything-anything/anyname.php`, where `NumericID` is the number `1084` to be removed in this case.

Comment: I am not familiar with .htaccess but can you explain me what to pass in {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f, {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and {REQUEST_URL}.

Comment: Modified my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks :) your code works but need your small help i am getting two times php in this url http://www.example.com/profilephp.php Want to remove php after profile

Comment: Okay. I think I know why. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Updated. Please give it another try.

Comment: @Manan Could you please copy-paste in a comment the complete URL for the test?

Comment: I am complicating the rule. Please test again, I updated my answer.

Comment: But the entered URL `letsnurture.com/demo/tutoringhut/jerome-smith/profilephp.php` doesn't have the number. It must hold a number immediately after the domain, as depicted in your question.

Comment: Original url: www.letsnurture.com/demo/tutoringhut/1084-jerome-smith/profile.php. After entering url in browser http://www.letsnurture.com/demo/tutoringhut/jerome-smith/profilephp.php

Comment: check this url www.letsnurture.com/demo/tutoringhut/1084-jerome-smith/profile.php

Comment: OK. Checked the link. I see what's the problem. ¿Did you try with the last update in my answer?

Comment: Yes. I have paste that code in .htaccess. But still not working :(

Comment: I tested again and realized the number doesn't follow the domain  in the URL, as the example in your question. That's the reason for the strange behavior. I will modify the rule.

Comment: @Manan Modified it to capture the number in any position inside the URL path. Hope it works now.